# What is the relationship between block, gear speed and derailleur? With Pictures

Tags: derailleur, 7-speed

I am buying a new bicycle. The seller tells me it is "14 speed with 8 speed block, but the derailleur won't reach the lowest gear, so I will switch to 7 speed block".

How many gears will the bicycle have, what problems can I expect from this setup?

I have some photos:

[image]
[image]
\

Comment: It sounds like someone is trying to sell you an 8 speed bike with the wrong (7 speed) shifters!  I won't buy it.

Comment: Block is slang for shifter im guessing? Never heard that term before.

Comment: I'm guessing that block is short for cassette/freewheel.  It's a 14 speed bike with a 7 speed rear shifter. It will only be able to use 7 of those gears in the back because of the limitations of the shifter. I'm pretty sure I've heard the British blokes on GCN refer the the cassette as "block".

Comment: @Kibbee Do you think it's a) the dereilleur is faulty or b) the cassette is non-original and replaced at some point?

Comment: I am guessing the reasons its 8 speed is the rear wheel was changed at some time, and an 8 speed hub was chosen availability and/or price being most likely factors. 7 and 8 speed hubs are mostly incompatible, so a new cluster was required. The cog pitch for 7 and 8 speed clusters is the same, the 8 speed cluster will work perfectly using only 7 cogs. This choice would have been made to avoid buying new snifters and derailleur. To remove a cog will need a spacer and pulling apart the cluster (or a new one). If you buy the bike leaving as is would be a good choice

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this setup - it would not put me off a bike I might otherwise buy.

Comment: Now that I've seen the pictures, I'll agree with @mattnz, but only because the bike doesn't have click shifters, but instead has the old-style tension shifters on the downtube.  In this case, I'd expect the problem with not engaging the "8th" gear, has to do with cable tensions and / or limiter screws not set properly.

Comment: Actually, the down tube shifters of 7 speed era were indexed.

Comment: @mattnz, the seller has come back to me and said "I've now got a 6 speed set up which fits much better.  They're old school Joytech hubs with quick releases laced to Weinmann alloy rims." What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Sheldon Brown to the rescue: http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ba-n.html#block

- Short for freewheel block; cluster.

My understanding is that the bike has 7 speed shifters and for some reason 8 speed freewheel. Only 7 cogs work, so the seller is planning to switch to 7 speed freewheel. 7 and 8 speed freewheels nearly same distance between cogs, so wrong freewheel can actually work the way described.

One possible problem is that 8 speed is wider than 7, so the frame may have been bent to make room for the wider freewheel and may be bent at the process.

Comment: It looks like a steel frame, in which case it is OK to spread it accommodate the wider wheel.

Comment: It's OK if you know what you are doing but it isn't that difficult to mess it up and the seller doesn't seem very professional.